# Market share of GWT versions

Tags: gwt

Is there any resource that estimates what percentage of GWT-using web sites are built with each version of GWT? As providers of a GWT-compatible library, we're trying to decide which minimum version to require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [GWT surveys](http://www.gwtproject.org/gwt_surveys.html) available for 2012, 2013 and 2015.

Question 4.2 this year was "What version of GWT are you using?"

This was the result:

[image]

Keep in mind that this is based on the responses of just over 1000 developers. So you can decide how representative this result is.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. For my reference, I followed your link to the [2012](https://vaadin.com/documents/10187/b74a2275-232d-4d55-9158-fad1c8da5230#page=24) and [2013](https://vaadin.com/documents/10187/42fbbec4-51c8-426b-8aa8-fe46129353a3#page=23) results, both of which also show >80% adoption of a new version within one year.